# Obtain Metadata from XML code within Visual Studio

Tags: sql, xml, visual-studio

The Visual Studio reports include XML code with SQL embedded in between    "/CommandText" & “/CommandText”. Is there an easy way to extract the SQL code and specifically list out what tables are being used? And maybe even which columns are being used? The manual process is too long since there are many reports we are doing this with and each has multiple queries being used. We are looking for a way to automate the process of extracting reporting metadata from the XML code. If there are any other methods for this we’d love to hear them as well.

Comment: Most programming and scripting languages include an XML parser.  So, the most direct way would be to find someone who knows [tag:python] or [tag:perl] or [tag:powershell] or [tag:C#] to write some code to extract the data you need.

Comment: You speak about Visual Studio... Which language are you coding?